# Problem to interrupt a endless thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Hy everyone!

I have a Thread who updates a view over the Observer Pattern. The update is working  well, but the problem is that the interrupt doesn't work. Please help.

Main:

```
public class Main {

    public static Sensor s;
    public static Thread t;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        s = new Sensor (1);
         t = new Thread(){

            @Override
            public void run() {

                Random r = new Random ();
               while (!isInterrupted())
               {
                    try {
                       s.setTemp(r.nextInt(40));

                        s.notifyObservers(s.getTemp());
                       sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
               }


            }

        };
       JFrame jf = new JFrame();
       jf.setVisible(true);
       s.addObserver(jf);
       t.start();

    }

}
```

View (interrupt button):

```
private void bt_stopActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
     Main.t.interrupt();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `Thread.sleep()` throws an `InterruptedException`, your `interrupted` thread flag is set to `false` (refer to JavaDoc for `Thread.sleep()` for that), so you need to add `interrupt()` or `break` in your `catch` clause.